# Laravel: Display error message on search filter

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code where i want the user to search for their ideal hotel using the drop down list price, distance and rating. Now when the user selects one of these filters it will display a hotel, however i want a message to say ' no hotels found based on this criteria' when the user cannot find their hotel. Here is the following code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
  $distances = DB::table('posts')->select('distance')->distinct()->get()->pluck('distance')->sort();
  $prices = DB::table('posts')->select('price')->distinct()->get()->pluck('price')->sort();
  $rooms = DB::table('posts')->select('room')->distinct()->get()->pluck('room');
  $ratings = DB::table('posts')->select('rating')->distinct()->get()->pluck('rating')->sort();

 $post = Post::query();

 if ($request->filled('price')) {
  $post->where('price', $request->price);
  }

  if ($request->filled('distance')) {
   $post->where('distance', $request->distance);
 }
  if ($request->filled('room')) {
   $post->where('room', $request->room);
  }
 if ($request->filled('rating')) {
  $post->where('rating', $request->rating);
  }


return view('Pages.search', [
  'distances' => $distances,
   'prices' => $prices,
   'rooms' => $rooms,
   'ratings' => $ratings,
   'posts' => $post->get(),
  ]);

 }
```

The view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   <h1><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}   
         @for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
             @if($i <= $post->rating)
               <label for="star-5" class="star">  
               <i class="fas fa-star"span class="star star--gold"></span></i>
             </label>
             @else
         @endif
   @endfor

   </a>
   </h1>



          <div class= "about">
              <p>{{ $post->About }}</p>
          </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{{$post->image}}" height = 200 width =200>
            </div>
    <hr>
```

@endforeach
@endsection

Comment: What type of message do you want? Are you talking about something similar to a bootstrap alert? It would be good to share your view as well

Comment: So if the search does not match the users criteria an error should appear saying 'no hotels found' also the view has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your message to the session MessageBag if your filter return empty and then display it in your view.

**In your Controller**

```
$posts = $post->get();

if($posts->count() == 0)
    return view('Pages.search', compact('distances', 'prices','rooms','ratings','posts'))
        ->withErrors(['no_post_result' => 'There is no result ']);
else
    return view('Pages.search', compact('distances', 'prices','rooms','ratings','posts'));
```

**In your View**

```
@error('no_post_result')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Displaying customs errors is very similar to the Validation errors from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: Do i get rid of the original Return view (pages.search thing and replace it with that

Comment: yes it needs to be replaced, I also used `compact()` function to make it look cleaner